# Why if I create a trigger instead of update in SQL Server 2005, my table doesn't update?

Tags: sql

First I create a table with this script :

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee_Demo] (
    [Emp_ID] [bigint] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
[Emp_Name] [varchar] (55) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
[Emp_Sal] [decimal](10, 2) NULL 
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and then I create another table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee_Demo_Audit] (
 [Emp_ID] [int] NULL ,
 [Emp_Name] [varchar] (55) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
 [Emp_Sal] [decimal](10, 2) NULL ,
 [Audit_Action] [varchar] (100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
 [Audit_Timestamp] [datetime] NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

after that I create an `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` trigger on table `employee_demo`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgInsteadOfUpdate ON dbo.Employee_Demo
INSTEAD OF Update
AS
declare @emp_id int, @emp_name varchar(55), @emp_sal decimal(10,2), @audit_action varchar(100);
select @emp_id=i.Emp_ID from inserted i;
select @emp_name=i.Emp_Name from inserted i;
select @emp_sal=i.Emp_Sal from inserted i;  
IF UPDATE (Emp_sal)
begin
BEGIN
BEGIN TRAN
    if(@emp_sal>=1000)
    begin
    RAISERROR('Cannot Insert where salary fewer then 1000',16,1); ROLLBACK; end
    else begin
    insert into Employee_Demo_Audit(Emp_ID,Emp_Name,Emp_Sal,Audit_Action,Audit_Timestamp) values(@emp_id,@emp_name,@emp_sal,@audit_action,getdate());
    COMMIT;
    PRINT 'Record Updated -- Instead Of Update Trigger.'; END; end
end
```

I don't know why if I update table `employee_demo` with this script :

```
UPDATE employee_demo 
SET emp_name = 'ZHEE' 
WHERE emp_id = 1
```

the name of `emp_id = 1` is doesn't change...

Why ????

Comment: Interesting that the `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` trigger contains code that references *inserted* records and performs an `INSERT` action. Was this intentional?

Comment: I think you need `after update trigger` and not `instead of update`.

Comment: i got it from Google.com.. lol,, i want to learn `instead of update` trigger.. and when i used this script i got confuse why my table is not update if the update column is not emp_sal.. and all i want to do is, if the emp_sal is updated then the prev data of employee_demo will be inserted to table employee_demo_audit.. if the update is not emp_sal then it just do like usual, update the field of table employee_demo ..

Comment: Also - you're operating under a **false assumption** about triggers; any trigger in SQL Server is fired **once per batch** - so if you insert 50 rows at once, the trigger is fired **once** and the pseudo table `Inserted` contains those 50 rows that are being inserted. A statement like yours here: `select @emp_id=i.Emp_ID from inserted i;` will pick at random one of the rows inserted - but that's really not what you want. You need to **rewrite the trigger** to take into account that it's `Inserted` table might contain **multiple rows** and deal with that appropriately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `instead of` trigger *replaces* the default behavior.  Your trigger appears to perform an update only if the `Emp_sal` column is being changed. If that column is not being updated, no update statement is executed.

Comment: so if i dont update emp_sal the update statement **Will not execute any update statement**. 
is there any way to avoid it ??. 

is my trigger is in wrong way ??. 

or is it the rule of `instead of` trigger ??.

Comment: I believe you must provide the default action if you have certain cases when you want it to occur.  You are completely replacing the default action with the trigger - it doesn't "fall through" and execute it.

Comment: can u give me some example of instead of update trigger.. i'm newbie of using t-sql , this things is make me crazy.. @@

Comment: I think you're pretty close to what you want.  Just put an `else` block with the check for the column name and execute the regular `update` that you want in there.

Comment: The regular update is the one that would have happened if you didn't have the `instead of` trigger.

Comment: well i thought it would be do by automatically from sql, but if i have to put it directly on my trigger.. then i have no choice.. - anyway thanks for ur info..

Answer (score 0):

could this be related to the fact that you use bigint for the a id in your source table and just regular int in your audit table?

Comment: i dont think so.. coz i have a condition on my trigger , it will fire if the column that will be update is emp_sal, so if i update column emp_name it should not fire that trigger, and my table should be updated, but it doesnt..

Comment: That's the issue.  The trigger *always* fires, and yours replaces the `UPDATE` with no action.